# How can I connect my contract`s methods

Tags: web3js

I called the function of the distributed contract. The call() function works well.

```
const call = () => {
    const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "contract Address";
    const address = "my EOA";
    const testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    // console.log(testContract.methods);
  
    testContract.methods.currentBalance().call({from:address}).then(console.log);
  };
  call();
```

However, if I call send(), an error occurs.

this is send() code

```
const send = () => {
    const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "contract Address";
    const address = "my EOA";
    const testContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
  
    testContract.methods.funding(10000).send({from:address}).then(console.log);
  };
  send();
```

this is the error
[image]

I think the problem is digital signature. But
I don`t use a MetaMask.
How do I solve this problem?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

The method eth_sendTransaction() is used when you want your node to sign the transaction for you using an unlocked account. But if you're connected to a node that doesn't support this method, you should sign the transaction yourself and then send the transaction via the `eth_sendRawTransaction` method or use  `web3.eth.signTransaction()`, and then use `web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction()` to submit the signed transaction to your node.